# Changing "10%" ( a text field) to 0.1 (a decimal field) in a postgresql table

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table with a text field for percentage, i.e. it shows "10%" - I want to convert this column to show 0.1

I've done this previously in pandas, but would like to do it directly in postgresql

Example data below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE prices;

INSERT INTO prices VALUES
('{
    "0": {
        "Name": "CompX",
        "Percentage": "7.5%",
        "index": 1,
        "Date": "2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "1": {
        "Name": "CompY",
        "Percentage": "20%",
        "index": 1,
        "Date": "2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "2": {
        "Name": "CompX",
        "Percentage": "19%",
        "index": 2,
        "Date": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
}');
```

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model

Comment: Unfortunately the database that I'm working with is in this format